# Delete hidden files from sever except .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server, hidden-files

A couple of days back, I noticed that my server has a almost 1000 plus hidden directories and files that are exact replicas. Let me give you an example.

Level 1 Directory has the following sub-directories and files:

- wp-content
- wp-includes
- index.php
- wp-mail.php

Now, I notice that along with these 4, there are hidden files like these:

- ._wp-content
- ._wp-includes
- ._index.php
- ._wp-mail.php

Also, if these sub-directories too have further sub-directories (several levels deep), the same duplication has happened over there too. I'm not sure how did that happen (might have happened when I migrated from site from one server to another).

**Anyways, my question is how do I delete all these duplicate and hidden files with prefixes "._" (ignore quotes)** - including ones that are 3-4 sub-directories deep. Also such that .htaccess files or other important files/directories are not deleted.

Mine is a Wordpress site and I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find` utility:

```
find /path/to/search -name "._*" | xargs rm
```

or as an alternative

```
find /path/to/search -name "._*" -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

where `/path/to/search` has to be replaced by the base location in your local file system that you want to start the search in.

Comment: Does this mean something like this?


~/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html/

Also, how can I ensure a simpler way to rollback this delete action in case something goes wrong?

Comment: And how do I delete it then? Because the find util will only display the list of files. Right?

Comment: First you can replace the `rm` by something like `ls` first for a test, second you also can use `mv` instead and move all that to some safe location, but most sense of all makes a simple reliable backup that you should have available at all times anyway.

Comment: And no, the above commands will _not_ only list files, they will remove them. Please take a closer look.

Comment: My bad... Missed the rm. 

So, I'm thinking of doing something like this.. What do you think? Will this work?

`find  ~/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html/ -name "._*" | xargs mv -rp ~/home/admin/web/abcbackup`

Comment: Actually for a `mv` the second alternative is easier to handle if it comes to shell escaping: `find ~/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html/ -name "*~" -exec mv -rp "{}" ~/home/admin/web/abcbackup \;`   Though I am not aware of the flags `-rp` in a normal `mv` command...